# How to add predicate for one to many relation Core Data iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am having 2 table in core data
Product and Option

A product can have multiple options, now I would like to get product having a specific option.

I have no idea how to write predicate where clause for this

[image]

Its crashes with error ( *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
) when I try below code

```
-(Product*)getProdcutFromDB{

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSError *error;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *orderEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                    entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:orderEntity];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" options.optionID == '14'"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

Product* orderEntityForProdcut=nil;
if (fetchedObjects.count>0) {
    orderEntityForProdcut=(Product*)[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",orderEntityForProdcut.productName);
    NSLog(@"%@",orderEntityForProdcut.options);

    return orderEntityForProdcut;
}

return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you have to use `SUBQUERY()`.

(The separate string is to make it easy to read on SO.)

```
NSString *predicateFormat = @"SUBQUERY(options, $o, $o.optionID == %@).@count > 0"; // The "> 0" condition could also be "== 1", depending on your need.

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, optID];
```

**Aside:** It's best not to hard-code property names in strings.  It's better to write the above as:

```
// These would be defined somewhere that could be imported as needed.
NSString *const kOptionsKey = @"options";
NSString *const kOptionIDKey = @"optionID";

NSString *predicateFormat = @"SUBQUERY(%K, $o, $o.%K == %@).@count > 0";

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat,
                                      kOptionsKey, kOptionsIDKey, optID];
```

The idea is that if the property name is changed, a single constant is all that needs updating.  This also prevents the more common occurrence of a typo in the property name within a string.

Comment: Thanks, Great its working, could you please also suggest how can I add "AND" here I mean if I need the product which must have option id 12,13 and 14

Comment: Just define each of those predicates separately and then combine them using `NSCompoundPredicate`.

Comment: Can you provide a sample I am new to predicate :(

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat,
                              kOptionsKey, kOptionIDKey, @"15"];
    NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat,
                               kOptionsKey, kOptionIDKey, @"14"];
   
    
    // Add the predicates to the NSArray
    
    NSArray *subPredicates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:predicate1, predicate2, nil];
    
    NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];

Comment: Hi Avi, can I add to properties in SUBQuery like ID an Name and final predicate will be an array of this combination ???

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Avi for you answer, My problem has been resolved
Now update code is here using Multiple Predicate  with AND condition

After this code I am able to get list of Product having optionId="" and optionId="" and so on.....

```
-(Product*)getProdcutFromDBNew{

AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;

NSError *error;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *orderEntity = [NSEntityDescription
                                    entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:orderEntity];

// These would be defined somewhere that could be imported as needed.
NSString *const kOptionsKey = @"options";
NSString *const kOptionIDKey = @"optionID";

NSString *predicateFormat = @"SUBQUERY(%K, $o, $o.%K == %@).@count > 0";


NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat,
                          kOptionsKey, kOptionIDKey, @"12"];
NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat,
                           kOptionsKey, kOptionIDKey, @"14"];


// Add the predicates to the NSArray

NSArray *subPredicates = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:predicate1, predicate2, nil];

NSCompoundPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];



// NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" ANY options.name == 'Size'"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:compoundPredicate];

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

Product* orderEntityForProdcut=nil;
if (fetchedObjects.count>0) {
    orderEntityForProdcut=(Product*)[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",orderEntityForProdcut.productName);
    NSLog(@"%@",orderEntityForProdcut.options);

    return orderEntityForProdcut;
}

return nil;
```

}